# insert 2 images together

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make this design from figma ui design and need to make the 2 pic inside each other but when i do it there is a space between them also the shaded part in the right pic how can i make it
[image]

but it did not work so It comes in this shape
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: 235,
                  height: 235,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(
                        'assets/images/back1.png',
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: 279,
                  height: 279,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(
                        'assets/images/back1.png',
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So what widget or things to add to make the 2 pic mixed

Comment: Try use 'Positioned' with Stack. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html

Comment: could you please add the image file too?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Stack` and `Positioned` ,try this:

```
Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/back1.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      width: 235,
                      height: 235,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/back1.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      width: 279,
                      height: 279,
                    ),
                  ),
                  
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Row` Widget and size the first image to have half screen using `MediaQuery`
then wrap the `Row` it's self to stack and add other one over the stack and position it wherever you want !

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to export the two images together in Figma, forming a single image. You can do this by **selecting both images > Group > Export**. So you don't need almost any code to put them together. I know that's not the point, but it's a creative and valid solution for your case. I hope it helps.